# How to anchor one div to another and keep them responsive

Tags: javascript, jquery, css, vue.js, tooltip

I have a UI built in vue.js that I need to add tooltips to. I need the tooltips to be placed to the left or right of a specific div in the UI. I've been able to get my desired look by setting the tooltips to position absolute but this is not responsive so on some screens the tooltip does not align with the target div.

[image]

The UI is fairly complex so I'm trying to avoid having to rebuild the layout with flexbox/grid. I'm looking for a way to 'anchor' the tooltip to its corresponding divs using javascript.

https://codepen.io/joeymorello/pen/ZEeWmGd Here I am playing with append to and insertBefore but I would still need to fine-tune each tooltip location using CSS. Is there a way to just anchor one div right next to another div so the tooltip always follows its parent div?

```
const head = document.querySelector('.head') 
const body = document.querySelector('.body') 

const toolTipOne = document.querySelector('.tool-tip-1')
const toolTipTwo = document.querySelector('.tool-tip-2')

$(toolTipOne).appendTo(head);
$(toolTipTwo).insertBefore(body);
```

Answer (score 1):

Apply `position: relative` to `.body` and append the tooltip inside it. Then you can easily position it with `absolute` relative to position of `.body` using `top`, `left` etc:

https://codepen.io/tilwinjoy/pen/QWpNJdY

Answer (score 0):

Why not use pure css for this? You can use position relative on the element, then use its pseudo `::after` element and set its position to absolute. Then call on the left, top, right and/or bottom properties to place your pseudo element on the page relative to its parent that has position relative set.

```js
// example of how to change the content of a pseudo tag with JS and CSS variables using the root element

let root = document.documentElement

let headTTInfo = 'Maybe you want to change the Head tooltips content via JS?'
let bodyTTInfo = 'Here is content for your body elements tool tip generated with JS.'

root.style.setProperty('--body', `"${bodyTTInfo}"`)
root.style.setProperty('--head', `"${headTTInfo}"`)
```

```css
:root {
  --head: 'this is content for your head elements tool tip';
  --body: 'this is content for your body elements tool tip'
}
  /* This min-width on the body will ensure that your absolutely positioned element 
     is within the body and its display is not completely taken out of the 
     viewable container,   
     125px(tooltip offset) + 500px(width of parents) + 125px(tooltip offset) = 750
     gives us 10px padding on each side if screen width less than the width of the 
     parents elements, we do this because postion absolute takes its positioned elements
     out of the normal flow of the document. */
body {
  min-width: 770px; 
}

.head {
  margin: 0 auto;
  width: 500px;
  height: 250px;
  background-color: green;
  position: relative;
}

.body {
  margin: 1rem auto;
  width: 500px;
  height: 250px;
  background-color: pink;
  position: relative;
}

.head::after {
  content: var(--head); 
  position: absolute;
  left: -125px;
  top: 40%;
  width: 100px;
  height: auto;
  padding: 5px;
  background-color: teal;
}
.body::after {
  content: var(--body); 
  position: absolute;
  left: 515px;
  top: 40%;
  width: 100px;
  height: auto;
  padding: 5px;
  background-color: orange;
}
```

```html
<div class="container">
  <div class="head">HEAD</div>
  <div class="body">body</div>
</div>
```